# Getting data validation list to populate a table

Tags: vba, excel, validation, vlookup

I have a Data Validation list in cell `T3` in `Sheet3` of my workbook. The list contains location names. In `sheet1` of my workbook I have all the data for all locations in tables next to each other, e.g

**location 1|date|score|percentage|target|   |location 2|date|score|percentage|target| etc....**

I am looking to select a location from the drop down list and that will copy in the relevant table to `sheet3`. So you just select a location and can see the data. I'm wondering if the best way to go about this is formulas or to use `VBA` (my experience with using drop down lists in `VBA` is limited). Here is something that I am currently working on but it is incomplete at the moment and still leads to the question of 'is there a faster way to do this in `VBA`'. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated! (my validation list is called `List1`)

> =IF(ISNUMBER(A2),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A:$EG,MATCH(List1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0),FALSE)),0),"")

The idea is that i could have a table of formulas so depending on the list value, different data would appear.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't complete but it should get you started / give you some ideas

```
Sub CopyTable()

Dim colNo, lastRow As Integer
Dim ws1, ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' assign the worksheet variables
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

colNo = Application.Match(ws1.Range("T1"), ws1.Range("A1:R1")) ' work out which column the required table starts in

lastRow = ws1.Cells(10000, colNo).End(xlUp).Row ' work out the last row of the table

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, colNo), ws1.Cells(lastRow, colNo + 4)).Copy ws3.Range("A1") ' copy the table

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the boost and the start point Absinthe! Shall put some work in on this and get back with the results :)